How to debug this makefile error on a dune project
I cloned this repo
https://github.com/cucapra/gator and tried to run the makefile as per the first instruction in README. It seems to have already setup a dune project and just needs a build but I keep getting this error.
[ bobalex: ~/Gator/gator ]$ make
dune exec bin/gatorc.ml
make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 1


Any clue as what this could be?
This is log in _build
 dune exec bin/gatorc.ml
# OCAMLPARAM: unset
# Shared cache: disabled
# Shared cache location: /home/bobalex/.cache/dune/db
# Workspace root: /home/bobalex/Gator/gator
# Auto-detected concurrency: 4
# Dune context:
#  { name = "default"
#  ; kind = "default"
#  ; profile = User_defined "default"
#  ; merlin = true
#  ; fdo_target_exe = None
#  ; build_dir = In_build_dir "default"
#  ; instrument_with = []
#  }
$ /home/bobalex/.opam/cs3110-2024fa/bin/ocamlc.opt -config > /tmp/dune_3ab5cb_output

Thanks in advance.

That error make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 1 means that the command that make invoked exited with an error code 1.  That's all make knows about it.  If the command make invoked didn't print any errors or give you any information about why it exited with a non-success error code, there's not much we can say about it.  However, it's not right to consider this a "makefile error".  Make did exactly what you asked, and it's just telling you the command it ran appears to have failed.
